# Bubble Sorting numbers

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that bubble sorts numbers and keep getting a segmentation fault. Any suggestion?

```
void bubblesort(struct Record *ptr, int records, int (*fcomp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    long c, d, i;    
    struct Record *sa, *sb, sc;

    for (c = 0 ; c < ( records - 1 ); c++)
    {
        for (d = 0 ; d < records - c - 1; d++)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < records - 1; i++)
            {
                if (fcomp(ptr+i, ptr+i+1) <= 0)
                {
                    /* Swapping */

                    sc  = sa[d];
                    sa[d]   = sb[d+1];
                    sb[d+1] = sc;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Any suggestion" - Don't use bubblesort.

Comment: You need to be running under a debugger.  This will give you more information.

Comment: @MitchWheat: When dealing with a nearly sorted set, bubblesort outperforms most algorithms.

Comment: @Fred: I'm aware of that: so does Insertion sort; But try using BubbleSort on too large a set and you're in for a world of pain. Why take a chance?

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behavior on accessing `sa`, `sb`.

```
sc  = sa[d];
sa[d]   = sb[d+1];
sb[d+1] = sc;
```

are all illegal because they're just dangling pointers.

```
struct Record *sa, *sb
```

doesn't allocate any memory for `sa` and `sb`, and even if you did, I don't see how it would be relevant. They'd contain bogus values anyway.